# What is the best way to sort an IList<T> in .Net 2.0?

Tags: .net, .net-2.0

I have an `IList<T>` that I need to sort, and I would rather not copy the list if possible.  I've noticed that `ArrayList` has an `Adapter` static method that wraps the passed list without copying it, but this takes an `IList` and I have an `IList<T>`.  Is it safe to cast from a `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>` to a `System.Collections.IList` and just use the `Adapter` method?

Note that this is .Net 2.0, so LINQ is not an option.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844463/how-do-i-sort-ilistclass

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the blog of Paul Fox, I recommend the post "How to sort an IList": http://foxsys.blogspot.com/2007/06/how-to-sort-generic-ilist.html

Just in case that blog goes away in the future, I'll copy the post here:

---

**How to sort a generic IList**

Update

You can read and updated post about [sorting generic IList and List](http://foxsys.blogspot.com/2008/05/how-to-sort-generic-list-sorting-list.html). Many people will prefer the methods mentioned in the updated post.

Sorting a generic IList

I was trying to sort a generic IList<> and found a fairly simple way of doing it.

Step 1

You need to implement IComparable for the type contained in your IList. For this example I am going to use a simple Language Dto class.

```
public class LanguageDto : IComparable {
 private String name;
 public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }

 public LanguageDto(string name) {
     this.name = name;
 }

 #region IComparable Members
 public int CompareTo(object obj) {
     if (obj is LanguageDto) {
     LanguageDto language = (LanguageDto)obj;
     return this.name.CompareTo(language.name);
     }
     throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Cannot compare a LanguageDto to an {0}", obj.GetType().ToString()));
 }
 #endregion
}
```

STEP 2

Sort your IList. To do this you will use the ArrayList.Adapter() method passing in your IList, and then calling the Sort method. Like so...

```
ArrayList.Adapter((IList)languages).Sort();
```

Note: languages is of type "IList"

Languages should then be a sorted list of your type!

Comment: So he does just cast the IList<T> to an IList.  Why is that a safe cast to make?

Comment: Don't copy the whole post.  It would seem like the right thing to do to make sure content is preserved, but copying the whole post likely requires explicit permission from the copyright holder.  You can and should create a summary, though.

Comment: @EddieDeyo: I know this is a few years old, but it's because IList<T> doesn't really exist, instead it is a IList of LanguageDto, which of course is a IList of LanguageDto.  T is (mainly) a compile time illusion.  The "difference" between an IList<T>  and IList is that for IList Item[0] returns an Object, but for IList<T> Item[0] returns an Object which will always be a T, and if T is a struct/primitive the Object won't have been boxed. So, a cast from IList<T> to IList would be safe (unnecessary, but safe) but the reverse isn't

Answer (score 6):

You cannot cast IList(T) to IList.

After some sniffing with Reflector, it seems like ArrayList.Adapter(IList).Sort() will first copy the list to an object array, sort the array and then copy the array back to a list:

```
object[] array = new object[count];
this.CopyTo(index, array, 0, count);
Array.Sort(array, 0, count, comparer);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    this._list[i + index] = array[i];
}
```

You might get boxing overhead if T in your List(T) a value type.

If you need to alter the sequence of the objects in the list that you have, you can do it similarly:

```
IList<object> unsorted = ...
List<object> sorted = new List<object>(unsorted);
sorted.Sort(); 
for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.Countt; i++)
{
    unsorted[i] = sorted[i];
}
```

If the list is so huge (as in hundreds of million items) that you cannot make an extra copy in memory, I suggest using a List(T) in the first place or implement your favorite in-place sorting algorithm.

Comment: Yeah, but I'd said I was hoping to avoid copying the list.

Comment: don't copy it then and just say:

    unsorted = sorted;

Comment: @Hallgrim: sure you can.  http://ideone.com/bqzIpk4
        `IList x = new int[]{1,2,3, 4};
        IList<int> g = (IList<int>) x; 
        System.Console.WriteLine(g.Count);
        IList g2 = g as IList;
        System.Console.WriteLine(g2.Count);`

Answer (score 1):

Since the Sort method isn't on the IList interface you might consider creating your own:

```
interface ISortableList<T> : IList<T>
{
    void Sort();
    void Sort(IComparer<T> comparer);
}

class SortableList<T> : List<T>, ISortableList<T> { }

/* usage */
void Example(ISortedList<T> list)
{
    list.Sort();
    list.Sort(new MyCustomerComparer());
}
```

In general the parameter type you specify in your method should be the lowest common denominator of members you actually need to call. If you really need to call the Sort() method then your parameter should have that member defined. Otherwise you should probably load it into another object that can do what you want such as:

```
void Example(IList<T> list)
{
    list = new List<T>(list).Sort();
}
```

This should actually be pretty fast, almost certainly faster still than writing your own custom inline sort algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I know it isn't .NET 2.0 but I love LINQ so much and will endorse it every chance I get :)

**Simple Sort:**

```
var sortedProducts =
    from p in products
    orderby p.ProductName
    select p;

ObjectDumper.Write(sortedProducts);
```

**Sort by multiple conditions:**

```
string[] digits = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

var sortedDigits =
    from d in digits 
    orderby d.Length, d
    select d;
```

Both examples are from [101 Linq Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336756.aspx)

Comment: This is good.  Through the magic of google it's likely someone will arrive here looking for help who doesn't share the OP's 2.0 constraint.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort Lists (not ILists) of different classes without the need to create a seperate comparer class for all of them and still keep your entity classes clean (you don't want to implement IComparable), you can use the following (compatible with .NET 2.0):

```
public class DynamicComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{

    private Func<T, int> calculateFunc;
    private int calculateMultiplier;

    private Func<T, T, int> compareFunc;
    public DynamicComparer(Func<T, int> calculateFunc, bool reverse = false)
    {
        if (calculateFunc == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Delegate function 'calculateFunc' cannot be null.");
        }

        this.calculateFunc = calculateFunc;
        this.calculateMultiplier = reverse ? -1 : 1;
        this.compareFunc = null;
    }

    public DynamicComparer(Func<T, T, int> compareFunc)
    {
        if (calculateFunc == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Delegate function 'compareFunc' cannot be null.");
        }

        this.calculateFunc = null;
        this.compareFunc = compareFunc;
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        if (calculateFunc != null)
        {
            return (calculateFunc(x) - calculateFunc(y)) * this.calculateMultiplier;
        }
        if (compareFunc != null)
        {
            return compareFunc(x, y);
        }

        throw new Exception("Compare not possible because neither a Compare or a Calculate function was specified.");
    }
}
```

You'll also need the Func delegates if you're using .NET 2.0 (found on [Replacing Func with delegates C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982220/replacing-func-with-delegates-c-sharp)):

```
public delegate TResult Func<T, TResult>(T t);
public delegate TResult Func<T, U, TResult>(T t, U u);
```

Usage:

```
myList.Sort(new DynamicComparer<MyClass>(x => x.MyIntProperty) // Ascending
myList.Sort(new DynamicComparer<MyClass>(x => x.MyIntProperty, true) // Descending
```

Some simple unit testing:

```
[TestClass()]
public class DynamicComparerTU
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void SortIntList()
    {
        // Arrange
        dynamic myIntArray = new int[] {
            4,
            1,
            9,
            0,
            4,
            7
        };
        dynamic myIntList = new List<int>(myIntArray);

        // Act
        int temp = 0;
        for (int write = 0; write <= myIntArray.Length - 1; write++)
        {
            for (int sort = 0; sort <= myIntArray.Length - 2; sort++)
            {
                if (myIntArray(sort) > myIntArray(sort + 1))
                {
                    temp = myIntArray(sort + 1);
                    myIntArray(sort + 1) = myIntArray(sort);
                    myIntArray(sort) = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        myIntList.Sort(new DynamicComparer<int>(x => x));

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(myIntList);
        Assert.AreEqual(myIntArray.Length, myIntList.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i <= myIntArray.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(myIntArray(i), myIntList(i));
        }
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void SortStringListByLength()
    {
        // Arrange
        dynamic myStringArray = new string[] {
            "abcd",
            "ab",
            "abcde",
            "a",
            "abc"
        };
        dynamic myStringList = new List<string>(myStringArray);

        // Act
        myStringList.Sort(new DynamicComparer<string>(x => x.Length));

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(myStringList);
        Assert.AreEqual(5, myStringList.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("a", myStringList(0));
        Assert.AreEqual("ab", myStringList(1));
        Assert.AreEqual("abc", myStringList(2));
        Assert.AreEqual("abcd", myStringList(3));
        Assert.AreEqual("abcde", myStringList(4));
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void SortStringListByLengthDescending()
    {
        // Arrange
        dynamic myStringArray = new string[] {
            "abcd",
            "ab",
            "abcde",
            "a",
            "abc"
        };
        dynamic myStringList = new List<string>(myStringArray);

        // Act
        myStringList.Sort(new DynamicComparer<string>(x => x.Length, true));

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(myStringList);
        Assert.AreEqual(5, myStringList.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("abcde", myStringList(0));
        Assert.AreEqual("abcd", myStringList(1));
        Assert.AreEqual("abc", myStringList(2));
        Assert.AreEqual("ab", myStringList(3));
        Assert.AreEqual("a", myStringList(4));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
IList<object> unsorted = ...
IList<object> sortedList = unsorted.Orderby(x => x.Tostring()).Tolist();
```

this will give the sorted list on the particular field of the object.